# IOS Geolocation in Javascript does refuse work after returning to webpage

Tags: javascript, ios, geolocation

I was trying to code a little html/css/javascript game for Android and IOS, using the GEOLOCATION WATCH feature.
I am using an https webpage.
In Android everything works fine. In IOS a had to add an Geolocation Request feature. It asks me inside the browser for Safari and the webpage if I would allow geolocations.
This works fine if I stay on the page, where I ask for the geolocations.
But if I leave that page to show another page (separate webpage) and THEN RETURN back to that webpage where I ask for geolocation, the geolocation watch function refuses updating. Only in IOS. Why?

What I tried:

- IOS 12.2 and 14.4 => both the same
- Adding clearwatch() function at
  the top of the page before calling the geolocation function... does not work
- Refreshing the webpage via the browser ... does not work
- Closing Safari Browser totally, and reopening it... working
- scanning the internet for solutions... did not find any

What has to be added to my webpage, so that the geolocation continues working when I return back from another webpage to my geolocation-webpage?

Regards,
Roger

Comment: I tried some more: Firefox and Chrome on IPhone same problem as Safari.

Comment: Now I tried in html to open into a new window using <a href ... _blank> And closing the new window using window.close()... Doesn´t help either

Comment: Seems that security-guidelines in IOS simply do not allow this. I solved the problem by re-coding the multiple-webpages to a single-page-app.